# R: Exporting massive files within a loop

Tags: r, csv, export, stata, fwrite

I have a code that generates several very large dataframes in a loop. Each one has around 300 million rows so I run out of memory before the loop is over. I am trying to export each dataframe once it is constructed within the loop and then remove it to free up space in my R environment before I start constructing the next.

The issue is how to export these very large datasets. I tried using `fwrite` from the `data.table` package but when I open the csv file I get an empty csv file called Book1 instead. I also tried saving it as a dta file using `write.dta` from the `foreign` package but Stata tells me it is corrupted when I try opening it.

Comment: `fwrite` works just fine and that's what I'm using in such cases. Either you have an error in your code (and you don't show any code) or the issue is with how you are trying to open these files. E.g., I wouldn't dare trying to open such a large file with Excel.

Comment: You are absolutely right, @Roland! I tried openning with Stata and it worked fine! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When saving it as .csv with `fwrite` and opening it with Stata it worked perfectly!